# Get data set as numpy array from TFRecordDataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using the new **`tf.data` API** to create an iterator for the CIFAR10 dataset. I'm reading the data from two *.tfrecord* files. One which holds the training data (train.tfrecords) and another one which holds the test data (test.tfrecords). This works all fine. At some point, however, I need both data sets (training data and test data) as *numpy arrays*.

Is it possible to retrieve a data set as numpy array from a `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` object?

Comment: you obliged to use `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`tf.data.Dataset.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#batch) transformation and [`tf.contrib.data.get_single_element()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/get_single_element) to do this.
As a refresher, `dataset.batch(n)`
will take up to `n` consecutive elements of `dataset` and convert them into one element by concatenating each component. This requires all elements to have a fixed shape per component. If `n` is larger than the number of elements in `dataset` (or if `n` doesn't divide the number of elements exactly), then the last batch can be smaller. Therefore, you can choose a large value for `n` and do the following:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Insert your own code for building `dataset`. For example:
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(...)  # A dataset of tf.string records.
dataset = dataset.map(...)  # Extract components from each tf.string record.

# Choose a value of `max_elems` that is at least as large as the dataset.
max_elems = np.iinfo(np.int64).max
dataset = dataset.batch(max_elems)

# Extracts the single element of a dataset as one or more `tf.Tensor` objects.
# No iterator needed in this case!
whole_dataset_tensors = tf.contrib.data.get_single_element(dataset)

# Create a session and evaluate `whole_dataset_tensors` to get arrays.
with tf.Session() as sess:
    whole_dataset_arrays = sess.run(whole_dataset_tensors)
```